# react component using vega

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, vega

I'm trying to use [vega](https://vega.github.io/vega/) from a react component but without luck (might be installation problem).

I wrote a component with the following structure:

```
import vega from 'vega';

class Chart extends React.PureComponent {
...
  componentDidMount() {
    vega.parse(...)
  }
}
```

But I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined`

This leads me to conclude that the installation did not go as expected.

During installation, I do have problems since vega uses node-gyp and I'm on a windows environment (and also behind a proxy)

When installing node-gyp I got some problems with node-canvas (although according to the documents, vega should work without it)

Most of the documents disregard the installation of vega.

Has anyone tried installing it and using it with `import` - does it work?

Comment: I think you have to use `import * as vega from 'vega';`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in this topic, it seems that the documentation is insufficient but here is how I got it to work:

For installation, `npm install vega` might be enough for you if you're not on windows or under a proxy.

If you do have problems, these steps helped me:

1. install the windows-build-tools (`npm --add-python-to-path='true' install --global --production windows-build-tools`)
2. `npm install node-gyp`
3. install GTK2 (see https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows#install-manually)
4. `npm install vega`

As for usage, make sure that you get an example for the version of vega you intend to use (e.g. an example for vega 2 won't work on vega 3)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Approach:

So I am adding Vega charts to a react app and was having some problems getting vega charts to work "out of the box" even following this [article](https://medium.com/@pbesh/react-and-vega-an-alternative-visualization-example-cd76e07dc1cd). I then discovered [react-vega](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-vega) and it works great.

Steps to get it to work:

- `npm install react vega-lib react-vega --save`
- create new react class :

  `import {createClassFromSpec} from 'react-vega';
  export default createClassFromSpec('MyChart', { ...VEGA SPEC OBJ...});`
- use `<MyChart data={mydata}>` as a standard react component.